# How do I write this as mathematical notation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm diving into the world of math and stumbled upon the following question:

*If you put \$100 into your bank account every year for 10 years with an interest rate of 2%, how much money do you have after 10 years?*

I know that if I put \$100 dollars into the bank account and waited 10 years I would get $100 \cdot 1.02^{10}$. But what is the formula if I keep putting \$100 into the account every year?

I think I've figures out the answer using python

```
k = 100
p = 0.02

ks = 0 # store the intermediate sums
y = [ks := (ks + k) * (1 + p) for _ in range(0,10)]
```

```
[102.0,
 206.04,
 312.1608,
 420.404016,
 530.8120963199999,
 643.4283382463999,
 758.2969050113279,
 875.4628431115544,
 994.9720999737856,
 1116.8715419732614]
```

**But how do I write this as mathematical notation?**

Comment: Something like $100 (1.02^{10} + 1.02^9 + \cdots + 1.02^1)$?

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
k &= 100\\
p &= 0.02\\
y[i] &= \begin{cases}
0,& i = -1\\
(y[i-1]+k)\cdot (1+p),& i= 0\ldots 9
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: $$100 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n 1.02^i$$. If you just want 10 years substitute $n = 10$

Comment: Thanks all! Much appreciated!